# Outlook cannot make backup pst (error)?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, backup, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

I am trying to create a .PST backup, however during the process it basically skips inbox/sent and goes straight to importing 'sync errors' for a few minutes. When I try to open the created .pst in outlook, I find that each time, there are no messages, only sync issues. The errors in those are: 'Error synchronizing folder  [8004DF03-0-0-560]' and 'Error synchronizing message [800CCC0F-0-0-322]' 
Can anyone help?

Thanks :)

Comment: What steps are you taking to create the backup?

Comment: I am doing it by clicking file > open & export > import/export > export to file > .PST > click on my email address to backup all folders > select location > finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the free [Export Outlook Items to PST File](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookItemsExportPST/) tool to backup your mailbox. Hopefully it will not produce any errors.